# Which version of Hibernate is standalone (doesn't require a JPA implementation)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm looking for such a version but could'nt find Hibernate's release history on the net.

I tried using latest version of Hibernate at the time of writing, 3.6.0Final. But when I run my application I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.logic.BaseManager.<init>(BaseManager.java:14)
    com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.logic.MapSearchManager.<init>(MapSearchManager.java:42)
    com.st.wma.page.mapsearch.MapSearchPage.beforeRender(MapSearchPage.java:44)
    st.liotrox.page.WPage.doWrite(WPage.java:1712)
    st.liotrox.page.WPage.write(WPage.java:1626)
    st.liotrox.servlet.CIPRequestHandler.doRenderPage(CIPRequestHandler.java:164)
    st.liotrox.servlet.CIPRequestHandler.renderPage(CIPRequestHandler.java:95)
    st.liotrox.servlet.CIPRequestHandler.sendResponse(CIPRequestHandler.java:51)
    st.liotrox.servlet.AbstractRequestHandler.doHandleRequest(AbstractRequestHandler.java:183)
    st.liotrox.servlet.AbstractRequestHandler.handleRequest(AbstractRequestHandler.java:133)
    st.liotrox.servlet.RequestFilterChain.executeRequest(RequestFilterChain.java:60)
    st.liotrox.servlet.filter.AbstractRejectRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRejectRequestFilter.java:130)
    st.liotrox.servlet.filter.MaxUserRequestsFilter.filterRequest(MaxUserRequestsFilter.java:106)
    st.liotrox.servlet.RequestFilterChain.executeRequest(RequestFilterChain.java:56)
    st.liotrox.servlet.filter.AbstractRejectRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRejectRequestFilter.java:130)
    st.liotrox.servlet.RequestFilterChain.executeRequest(RequestFilterChain.java:56)
    st.liotrox.servlet.FilteredRequestHandler.handleRequest(FilteredRequestHandler.java:72)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.delegatesExecutionToRequestHandler(ApplicationServlet.java:833)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.doMonitoredRequest(ApplicationServlet.java:811)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.executeRequest(ApplicationServlet.java:706)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.doService(ApplicationServlet.java:563)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.service(ApplicationServlet.java:498)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:96)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1826)
    com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.logic.BaseManager.<init>(BaseManager.java:14)
    com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.logic.MapSearchManager.<init>(MapSearchManager.java:42)
    com.st.wma.page.mapsearch.MapSearchPage.beforeRender(MapSearchPage.java:44)
    st.liotrox.page.WPage.doWrite(WPage.java:1712)
    st.liotrox.page.WPage.write(WPage.java:1626)
    st.liotrox.servlet.CIPRequestHandler.doRenderPage(CIPRequestHandler.java:164)
    st.liotrox.servlet.CIPRequestHandler.renderPage(CIPRequestHandler.java:95)
    st.liotrox.servlet.CIPRequestHandler.sendResponse(CIPRequestHandler.java:51)
    st.liotrox.servlet.AbstractRequestHandler.doHandleRequest(AbstractRequestHandler.java:183)
    st.liotrox.servlet.AbstractRequestHandler.handleRequest(AbstractRequestHandler.java:133)
    st.liotrox.servlet.RequestFilterChain.executeRequest(RequestFilterChain.java:60)
    st.liotrox.servlet.filter.AbstractRejectRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRejectRequestFilter.java:130)
    st.liotrox.servlet.filter.MaxUserRequestsFilter.filterRequest(MaxUserRequestsFilter.java:106)
    st.liotrox.servlet.RequestFilterChain.executeRequest(RequestFilterChain.java:56)
    st.liotrox.servlet.filter.AbstractRejectRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRejectRequestFilter.java:130)
    st.liotrox.servlet.RequestFilterChain.executeRequest(RequestFilterChain.java:56)
    st.liotrox.servlet.FilteredRequestHandler.handleRequest(FilteredRequestHandler.java:72)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.delegatesExecutionToRequestHandler(ApplicationServlet.java:833)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.doMonitoredRequest(ApplicationServlet.java:811)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.executeRequest(ApplicationServlet.java:706)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.doService(ApplicationServlet.java:563)
    st.liotrox.servlet.ApplicationServlet.service(ApplicationServlet.java:498)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Upon searching, I find that `javax/persistence/EntityListeners` is part of Java EE 5/JPA 1.0 specification.

As my server (Tomcat) doesn't have a JPA implementation, I'm looking for a Hibernate version that doesn't require one. Which version is it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement the other answers: before Hibernate 3.6, Hibernate had some modules, like Annotations, Entity Manager and Core. This last one is the "original" Hibernate, with no JPA API dependency. From 3.6 and on, Annotations and Entity Manager were merged into Core. That said, you can still use Hibernate with any standalone application, or in Servlet engines, like Tomcat. You just need the JPA API in the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

for rectifying the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners" add the jar file **hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar** which is available in jpa folder of   hibernate home directory to your class path as value........ now compile and execute your program...

Answer (score 2):

If you have downloaded the hibernate distribution file then you will have the required and optional libraries in the lib sub folder just add them to your class path.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate *is* a JPA implementation and therefore needs the API jars to function. You don't need Tomcat to implement the JPA spec by itself.

As hinted in [The Hibernate forums entry 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityList'](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1007502)  you should loook for a JAR named hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar for Hibernate 3.6 . Other versions might differ, but the names are similar and should contain *jpa* or *persistence*.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate needs the JPA api if you want to use the HibernateEntityManager, which comes in its own Jar. Just add the API.jar to your classpath.