# ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners on Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, rest, jersey

I'm trying to built a web service based on Restfull and Jersey1.17. To deploy on Tomcat server.

In my project, I need to work with hibernate4 to communicate with my Oracle 11g XE database.

Each works fine alone stand alone: Hibernate works fine, and the web service too. But on Tomcat I got ClassNotFoundException

StackTrace here : `

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


cause mère 

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Utilities.HibernateSessionFactory.GetSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:25)
    DAO.data.GetArticle.sayHtmlHello(GetArticle.java:92)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


cause mère 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:97)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1310)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
    Utilities.HibernateSessionFactory.GetSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:22)
    DAO.data.GetArticle.sayHtmlHello(GetArticle.java:92)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


cause mère 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:97)
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1310)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
    Utilities.HibernateSessionFactory.GetSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:22)
    DAO.data.GetArticle.sayHtmlHello(GetArticle.java:92)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

`
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you attach your code?

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail in your question for us to help you. For example, what do you mean by `But once together, Nothing works anymore!`. Were you getting errors? And if so, what were they. Were you getting absolutely no response from your test pages? If so, state that. I would advise not starting over until you understand what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: What I mean by each works fine is this. I tested hibernate alone, and it gets data from my database, the connection, the mapping .. It's all fine. On the other hand the web service works fine when I only use a basic method that returns a string. The client calls it just fine. But when I try to call the method I used with hibernate, to get data from my database. I get errors.

Comment: Looks like your Hibernate JPA is missing for your project's depencency. Try to add Hibernate JPA jar in your lib.
This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667390/which-version-of-hibernate-is-standalone-doesnt-require-a-jpa-implementation

Comment: I added the hibernate JPA jar. And It still gives the "ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners" error !

Comment: Have you checked if the class that is not found is in your bundled WAR file by using something like http://jfind.sourceforge.net/?

Answer (score 1):

Add Hibernate-JPA, can be found at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-jpamodelgen/1.2.0.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.2.0.Final-dist.tar.gz/download